# Obtaining SurfaceView dimensions

Tags: android, resolution, surfaceview

I think I might be about to ask a dummy question, but I'm still new with Android programming, and I couldn't (despite all my efforts) find my answer on Google.

The thing is, I'm trying to develop a little game, with 2D Graphics. I want my "gaming board" to be at a specific position on my screen, so that I can display in-game informations above and below the box. But since there is beginning to be a lot of Android phones out there, I was thinking about getting "dynamic" values so that I can adapt my font size to every device.

My game is not in full screen (but it could be, it's no big deal), but in a window with no title bar.

I'm using an extension of the default `SurfaceView` class, implementing `SurfaceHolder.Callback`. I tried writing the following method :

```
public void getViewSize()
    {
        VIEW_WIDTH = this.getWidth();
        VIEW_HEIGHT = this.getHeight();
    }
```

but the values returned are zeroes.

Anyone got an idea (even if it means changing display strategy) ?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: If SurfaceView is subclassed and if onDraw(Canvas canvas) is overriden in that subclass, is the onDraw method executed? Looking at your problem, seems like it does but I'm doing the same thing but the control never enters onDraw. Please advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this:

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
  VIEW_WIDTH = canvas.getWidth();
  VIEW_HEIGHT = canvas.getHeight();
}
```

Comment: I want to do the exact same thing but the control never enters my onDraw() method. Please take a look at this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340847/subclassing-surfaceview-and-overriding-ondraw-to-change-surfaceview-parameters